# How to toggle a div element but be able enter data into an input field

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to create a from where the user can update certain information about themselves. I have a div element that only shows the field that is to be updated then when you click the div it shows the input field. However whenever i click the input field to enter some data, the div element hides the input field.

I understand why it is doing that as I am toggling the child elements however I cannot seem to be able to code it such that When you click anywhere in the div, the field toggles but be able to enter data into the input field as well, without it disappearing.

```
<div class="div_hover">Forename:
 <span class="form"><input type="text"  name="forename"></span></div>
```

And my jquery (so far) looks like:

```
$(function() {
//hides input form

  $('.form').hide();

  //click the div_hover to show input form
  $('.div_hover').click(function() {
    $(this).children().toggle();
  });
});
```

I tried to use `stopPropagation()` in various ways but nothing seems to work so far.

Comment: can you set up a http://jsfiddle.net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use  `if (e.target !== this) return;` inside your js click function to tell to toggle only when the parrent div itself is clicked and not the child span input. Take a look at this:

http://jsfiddle.net/csdtesting/82L0gkvj/

```js
$('.div_hover').on('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target !== this) return;
  $(this).children().toggle();
  alert('clicked the div_hover');
});
```

```css
.div_hover {
  padding: 20px;
  background: yellow;
}
span {
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='div_hover'>Forename:
  <span><input type="text"  class="as" name="forename"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is due to event propagation. Clicking on the input first triggers a click on the whole page, which is then "captured" to more specific elements (div_hover, form, then input), and finally bubbles all the way up again (in reverse order).

You could fix your problem by checking the event object passed onto the click handler, it contains a `target` property that will tell you which element was clicked on more specifically.

Unverified code to give you the idea:

```
$('.div_hover').click(function(e) {
  if (e.target === this) {  
    $(this).children().toggle();
  }
});
```